# Make a questions without auxiliary verb

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english, descriptive-grammar

As a non-native speaker, I found some context in movies or general speaking, they make a questions without an auxiliary verb for example

- Who knows the answer?
- Who wants to go to Thailand ?

Why those questions above do not need an auxiliary verb?  (Or actually they do ?)

Then, how do we identify when we must use an auxiliary verb to make a question ?

Comment: An auxiliary is only needed in questions with subject-auxiliary inversion. When the subject of a question is a *wh*-word like *who* or *what,* inversion is not needed.

Comment: Auxiliaries are required in yes-no questions, such as "Have you been to Rome?" which would elicit the answer "Yes, I have" or "No, I haven't". By contrast, where the question includes an interrogative word like "what", "which" "who" etc., as in your examples, no auxiliary verb is required.

Comment: So, is it correct to say - Which one you like? or Which one do you like?  Please explain and give supportive reason.

Comment: OK, to be more precise, auxiliaries are required in 'closed' interrogatives as opposed to 'open' interrogatives. The former kind has a closed set of answers such as in my previous example, but it also includes examples like "Is he dead or alive?" (answers: "He's dead, He's alive).Note the subject-auxiliary inversion.

Comment: When asking about subjects, don't use auxiliaries. Period. If it seems weird - think: auxiliaries are to enable inversion (You ask/Do you ask). How would we invert the questions you've provided? "Does who know the answer"? (Legit, but the meaning is different.) Or "Who does know the answer"? (Possible, but the structure doesn't change).

Answer (score 1):

All main clause interrogatives but those questioning the subject have subject-auxiliary inversion and those lacking an auxiliary verb require the addition of dummy-*do*.

*How **do** you answer this question?*

*Who **do** you know best?*

***Do*** I know you?

*He went home.*

*He **did** go home.*

***Did*** he go home?

We question the subject using interrogative words *who*, *which* or *what* only. We may use an auxiliary verb, but there is no inversion.

*Who came back early?*

*Who **can** come back early?*

*What dropped from the tree?*

*What **did** drop from the tree?*

*Which (shop) has the best apples?*

*Which (shop) **will** have the best apples?*

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct to say

1. What makes her flatmate happy?
   or
2. What did make her flatmate happy?

Comment: Answers should not be used to ask different questions. Please use the "Ask Question" button on the home page to create a new question thread. You can link to this question for context.